# Diesel exhaust data, road vs. test lab

Tags: environment, cars

Is there open data on [Diesel exhaust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel_exhaust)
(NOx or soot), comparing a number of the same cars

- on the road
- in the test lab ?

What I want to do is plot the correlation: if road NOx is around say 2 times test lab,
legislators could use test lab data and scale limits by this ratio, here 2.
(Or is this common practice and I just don't know it ?)

Answer (score 1):

The [German Umweltbundesamt](https://www.umweltbundesamt.de/daten/luftbelastung/aktuelle-luftdaten)
(Environment Agency) collects hourly data on NOx, ozone etc.
at several hundred places in Germany.
It seems that their web query GUI can export only one-hour .csv s,
but the nice people there have sent me data for whole years,
which can be read with pandas and plotted like this:

[image]

Also, from [EEA Europe](http://discomap.eea.europa.eu/map/fme/AirQualityUTDExport.htm) one can download 48-hour files for European countries -- not terribly useful for long-term studies.